# Composer instalation failed php version conflict

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am going to install composer in my laravel project i got an error like 
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

I tried

```
/var/www/html/pro $ composer install
```

Then i got

```
Problem 1
    - This package requires php ^7.1.3 but your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for joshbrw/laravel-module-installer ^0.1.4 -> satisfiable by joshbrw/laravel-module-installer[v0.1.4].
    - joshbrw/laravel-module-installer v0.1.4 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
  Problem 3
    - laravel/framework v5.7.9 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.8 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.7 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.5 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.4 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.28 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.27 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.26 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.25 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.24 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.23 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.22 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.21 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.20 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.2 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.19 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.18 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.17 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.16 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.15 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.14 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.13 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.12 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.11 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.10 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.1 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.0 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.7.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.7.x-dev, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.12, v5.7.13, v5.7.14, v5.7.15, v5.7.16, v5.7.17, v5.7.18, v5.7.19, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.24, v5.7.25, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.




 similarly i tried
     /var/www/html/prol $ composer require spatie/laravel-medialibrary

    Got error

Using version ^6.9 for spatie/laravel-medialibrary
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - This package requires php ^7.1.3 but your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for joshbrw/laravel-module-installer ^0.1.4 -> satisfiable by joshbrw/laravel-module-installer[v0.1.4].
    - joshbrw/laravel-module-installer v0.1.4 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
  Problem 3
    - laravel/framework v5.7.9 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.8 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.7 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.5 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.4 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.28 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.27 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.26 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.25 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.24 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.23 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.22 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.21 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.20 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.2 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.19 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.18 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.17 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.16 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.15 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.14 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.13 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.12 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.11 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.10 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.1 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.7.0 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.7.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.7.x-dev, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.12, v5.7.13, v5.7.14, v5.7.15, v5.7.16, v5.7.17, v5.7.18, v5.7.19, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.24, v5.7.25, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
```

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be resolved by reading the error message.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the error?

Answer (score 5):

Your php version is not supported by laravel.
You have php 7.0.25, but laravel needs minimum php 7.1.3.

**Solution: upgrade your php to 7.1.3 or newer**

Server Requirements for latest laravel release:

```
PHP >= 7.1.3
OpenSSL PHP Extension
PDO PHP Extension
Mbstring PHP Extension
Tokenizer PHP Extension
XML PHP Extension
Ctype PHP Extension
JSON PHP Extension
BCMath PHP Extension
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8#server-requirements

**You can upgrade your php version with this commands:**

1. Add ondrej/php repository:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

2. Update your package lists:

> sudo apt-get update

3. Install php 7.3:

> sudo apt install php7.3 php7.3-common php7.3-cli

4. Install some php 7.3 extensions:

> apt install php7.3-bcmath php7.3-bz2 php7.3-curl php7.3-gd php7.3-intl
>   php7.3-json php7.3-mbstring php7.3-readline php7.3-xml php7.3-zip

5. Disable php 7.0:

> sudo a2dismod php7.0

6. Enable php 7.3:

> sudo a2enmod php7.3

7. Completely remove php 7.0 from your system:

> apt purge php7.0 php7.0-common php7.0-cli

Comment: how would you just remove the package? without running into *other* composer problems

Answer (score 3):

This should save the situation

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your php version. Use following line to update php

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install php7.1     //install php version 7.1 or other(5.6, 7.2)
sudo a2dismod php7.0        //Disable php 7.0
sudo a2enmod php7.1         //Enable php version 7.1
```

Comment: thanks but got error   Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1'

Comment: That was may be cause of ppa:ondrej/php. I have updated the answer because it's not looking fine in comment

Answer (score -3):

I solved this problem with this command, you just need to update the version of php
`composer update php`

[for windows users](https://medium.com/@stephenjudeso/upgrading-to-php-7-4-laragon-862b9d204d0c)

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?

Comment: Please share more details, `composer update php` makes no sense, especially if the installed PHP version (which does NOT change using composer!) is older than the minimum requirement for the packages to be installed