# How can I solve this problem that I have when updating composer through the terminal

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to install composer but it throws me this error " Problem 1
- mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.0, ..., v8.0.3] require php ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0 || ~7.2.0 || ~7.3.0 -> your php version (7.4.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
- mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.4, ..., v8.0.10] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
- Root composer.json requires mpdf/mpdf ^8.0 -> satisfiable by mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.0, ..., v8.0.10].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode."

Comment: Well I guess you are using Windows?

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66615935/5192105

Comment: The solution is literally written in the error message: ```Install or enable PHP's gd extension```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer instalation failed php version conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218267/composer-instalation-failed-php-version-conflict)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66368196/reference-composer-error-your-php-version-does-not-satisfy-requirements-afte

Answer (score 2):

Try to install the php extension using below command on Linux

```
sudo apt-get install php-gd
```

You can add your php version as `php7-gd`

If you are on Windows here is a detail of how to install php extension [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php)